# Displacement Heightmap is not tall enough

Tags: displacement, height-map

I created a plane subdivided it 100 times and added a displacement mod with a heightmap texture.  The height map looks great in my source heightmap creator and in Affinity photo as a well defined height map, but the displacement mod in blender, even with Strength maxed to 100, the plane still looks very flat as if the heigtmap has too little influence and I cannot increase the Strength enough get the plane to look like a landscape.  Image shows, imported heightmap in blender, landscape in external tool and affinity photo view of heightmap.
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you've scaled your object and you need to apply the scale? (Ctrl A)

Answer (score 0):

What kind of image format is this heightmap? I'm not an expert on JPGs, but as far as I know they only support 8 bit per channel. And I don't have Affinity either, but I've read that Affinity does support something like a single-channel heightmap with 16 bit (R16 format) and this seems to be what you have there.

Under the filename I can see (but it's not fully visible) "2048 x 2048, RGB byte, **R16F**..." for your JPG file. When I open a JPG file it would say "2048 x 2048, RGB byte, **SRGB8A8**". So I guess the 16 bit information is somehow squeezed into the 8 bit or more likely cropped - because on the right side you can see that there are larger white areas.

I suspect that those areas originally contained values above 1, but since the RGB values are limited to a 0 to 1 range, everything above is clipped and becomes 1, too. That would explain why you have those "plateaus" instead of the correct mountain tops.

I have no idea if there is a way to tell Blender that these JPGs should be treated as 16 bit files, but probably the best solution would be to export the heightmaps eitheras 16 bit PNG files or 16 bit TIFF greyscale images.

Answer (score 0):

Thx all for the ideas.  It turns out that my plane's scale was way too large compared to the size of the displacement.  Apparently a displaced object and displacement heightmap need to have some similarity of scale; (this even after applying scale).  Once I scale down my plane to about 1/20th of it's size, the displacement heightmap had the correct effect and worked as expected.  I think I had incorrectly assumed that the heightmap would be internally scaled to fit the displaced object.  If anyone knows how to calculate the maths here I'd love to hear.  While I tried to create a 2k and 4k heightmap, I have no clue what size my plane needs to be to be displaced correctly.  I have to use trial and error.